# install rqt on fuerte from source, Help

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

As a begginer, im having some problems with ros operating. Im trying to install rqt on raspi with fuerte from source. Im following this instructions
Build from source

Clone the git repositories qt_gui_core and rqt
Checkout the branch fuerte-devel for both repositories
Compile via rosmake rqt

But i cant manage to finally install it, i get some errors and i que dont really know how to execute each step. Could anyone give me some more concrete instructions to get it right?

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66255/install-rqt-on-fuerte-from-source,-help/) by [jefedruida](https://answers.ros.org/users/5283/jefedruida/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LovedByJesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8516/lovedbyjesus/) on 2013-11-07**:
See also similar question:
http://answers.ros.org/question/98466/rqt-install-in-fuerte-git-target-directories/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

JS's comment looks like it might work too.
But at the bottom of this page http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/UserGuide/Install/Groovy

Inexplicably there are fuerte instructions to build from source.
It looks like the fuerte instructions were merged into the groovy page at some point...

Do those work for you?

---

Originally posted by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) with karma: 211 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0